# Bring SVG to front of Leaflet

Tags: svg, leaflet

I'm trying to add an SVG element on top of my Leaflet map but it is hidden by the geoJSON markers as such: [SVG under markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKoZr.jpg)

This is the code I have so the SVG element is infront of the map

```
var svg = d3.select(this.map.getPanes().overlayPane).append('svg')
    .attr({
        "width": width,
        "height": height 
        })
    .on('click',function(){
        svg.remove();
});
```

I've tried this method but with no avail:

```
d3.selection.prototype.moveToFront = function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
    });
};

svg.moveToFront();
```

I was thinking I might need to .hide() the markers underneath the SVG but wasn't sure if that was the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: I believe that Leaflet's `overlayPane` is actually beneath `markerPane` in the rendering order, so to get your `svg` over the markers, you may want to try appending it to `markerPane` instead.

Comment: @nathansnider Thanks for your comment! I didn't realize there were other options and it turns out using 'popupPane' instead of 'overlayPane' worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone ever stumbles upon this I found another solution to my issue.

If I used .popupPane() the SVG element would cover the markers like I wanted but it also oddly moved my buttons. What I did instead was add another `<div>` element to my html (id = "map-nav"). I then edited my CSS so my "map" div was relative, "map-nav" was absolute and when I added my SVG to my map appended it to "map-nav" not "map". Here is the code example:

HTML

```
<div id="map" style="height:100%; width:100%;margin: 0"> </div>
        <div id="map-nav"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
```

JavaScript

```
//Define d3 margin
var margin = {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 40},
    width = 700 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 100 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

svg = d3.select("#map-nav").append('svg')
        .attr({
            "width": 500,
            "height": 500, 
        })
        .on('click',function(){
            svg.remove();
        });
```

CSS

```
svg {
    position: absolute;
    background-color:white;
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}
map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
}
map-nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 60px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

[Here is what it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avPQr.jpg)
Hope that helps someone who may also struggle with this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [L.DomUtil.toFront](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#domutil-tofront) and  [L.DomUtil.toBack](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#domutil-toback)

Also you have to Use [L.SVG](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#svg) layer
with set [pane](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#svg-pane) to 'markerPane'